# AMPL IDE error : The IDE cannot find the AMPL executable

Tags: optimization, ampl

I'm using windows 10 and I downloaded ampl package. When I ran `amplide.exe` file, I got this error:

```
The IDE cannot find the AMPL executable.
For assistance, copy this entire message and send it to licensing@ampl.com.
Search paths:
C:\Users\~\Desktop\GNE
C:/Users/~/Desktop/GNE/amplide/jre/bin/server
C:/Users/~/Desktop/GNE/amplide/jre/bin
C:/Users/~/Desktop/GNE/amplide/jre/lib/amd64
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\baron
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Anaconda3
C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\~\Desktop\GNE\amplide
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's rare. You could try to reinstall the AMPL and the AMPL IDE.

AMPL: [AMPL for students](https://ampl.com/products/ampl/ampl-for-students/)
AMPL IDE: [AMPL IDE](https://ampl.com/products/ide/)

Then, put your ampl with the student license inside the folder of IDE.

Regards